# Is there a way to change the RAFT leader in vaul?

Tags: hashicorp-vault, raft

I'm running a vault raft instance over a cluster of 5 servers. 2 of these servers are less performant than the others; I'm OK that they become leaders if the current leader fails, but I'd like to move the leader to the other servers when they get back online.

Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 1):

on any member of the raft use the cli: vault operator step-down

this will cause the current leader to step down. There is the potential that one of the less desirable servers will get leader again.